# Find multiple ODE solutions (counter example)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find some counter examples for the uniqueness of this ode
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = t \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

and initial condition: $y(0)=1$
I don't have idea of how I should start to think, may someone give me a (some) clue(s)?

Comment: Though it's somewhat obvious from the context (namely, you use the variable $t$), you should mention that you are looking for two (differentiable) functions which satisfy both the ODE **and** some initial condition $y(t_0) = y_0$.

Comment: You want to approach this by looking at where the existence and uniqueness theorem fails. In particular, for any neighborhood of $y = 1$, the function $f(t,y) = t \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ fails to be Lipschitz in $y$. This gives you a hint that when $y = 1$ there is the possibility for a breakdown of uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

$y=1$ and $y=\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ both satisfy the initial condition $y(0)=1$

Comment: How did you get these?

Comment: @PriscilaGutierres One is the constant solution, the other is from getting an explicit answer from separation of variables.

Answer (score -1):

This is a separable DE:

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = t \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy=t dt$

$sin^{-1}(y)+d=\frac{t^2}{2}+c$     (by integration)

$y= sin (\frac{t^2}{2} +a)$

Satisfy the equation for any $a$